# How do I get an animated gradient working with an icon in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, icons

I'm trying to get an icon to change color from the bottom up.

I was able to accomplish the desired results with normal text but the icon just goes invisible (or whatever color you set with `color`) instead of having a gradient fill.

I've tried various solutions from other posts but for whatever reason they have not worked out for me.

In the example code below, this color change should happen when the button is clicked.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { FaHourglass } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Button, styled } from "@mui/material";
import clsx from "clsx";

export default function App() {
  const [fill, setFill] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setFill(!fill);
  };

  return (
    <Root className="App">
      <FaHourglass
        id="fillThisIcon"
        className={clsx({ icon: true, iconFill: fill })}
      />
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Press to fill
      </Button>
      <b className={clsx({ icon: true, iconFill: fill })}>TESTING</b>
    </Root>
  );
}

const Root = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  width: "100%",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  gap: 10,

  "& > .icon": {
    fontSize: 100,
    color: "LightGrey"
  },

  "& > .iconFill": {
    fontSize: 100,
    color: "transparent",
    animation: "fillIcon infinite",
    animationDuration: "5s",
    animationTimingFunction: "ease-out",
    backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to top, SandyBrown 50%, LightGrey 50%)",
    backgroundSize: "100% 200%",
    backgroundPosition: "0% 0%",
    backgroundClip: "text"
  },

  "@keyframes fillIcon": {
    "0%": {
      backgroundPosition: "0% 0%"
    },
    "100%": {
      backgroundPosition: "0% 100%"
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Could you add more context - what is the icon? I see you have done a background clip on text - but is the icon text or an image?

Comment: @AHaworth The icon is from FontAwesome and it's an SVG.

Comment: So the color is set as transparent, and you have backgroundClip text. The fontawesome icon is not text so there’s nothing for the system to clip to and nothing is shown. If you look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it should help you put a little example of runnable code into your question which we can work with.

Comment: the background-image doesn't really work for SVG images. You would have to use a SVG gradient instead.  I take it that the main goal is to animate the text color, You could try to overlay the text and hide/show using a clip-path instead: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-snow-p3s79l?file=/src/App.js:306-317).